# How to quickly install Apache kudu quickstart vm?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, kudu

After checking on kudu official website, i got some instructions to download kudu virtualbox image and install vm. But that repository is no more available.

Is there any other way to get Kudu quickstart vm?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i done it in easiest way!!!

I created ec2 instance from "Cloudera Quickstart VM" ami available in community AMIs. Cloudera quickstart vm provides many preinstalled hadoop services which can be managed using single admin panel.

Kudu is not default service available in it. But can be added with some easy steps given in this document:
[Installing Apache Kudu on Cloudera’s Quickstart VM](https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-apache-kudu-on-clouderas-quickstart-vm-3bdc202ce142)